# Error with $http, passing parameter transformRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to post a data like (**email,role,home**) to my server using **angularjs**,but when I run the program it shows me a `error` like this which is following as....

```
ReferenceError: transformRequestAsFormPost is not defined
    at n.register [as send] (sectn.js:7)
    at sectn.js:72
    at n.$eval (angular.js:14466)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:14565)
    at register (sectn.js:71)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (get1.html:29)
```

to clear my error what should I add in my program. and my script
is

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);

app.controller('register', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.send = function register() {
        alert("test");
        $http.post("http://52.77.16.197:8000/subscribe/", transformRequest = transformRequestAsFormPost, data = JSON.stringify({ email: $scope.email, role: $scope.role, home: $scope.home }))
            .success(function (response) {
                alert("hi");
                $scope.persons = data;
            }).error(function (response) {
                if (response.message == "already_subscribed") {
                    alert("already_subscribed");
                }
                else {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
    }

});

   angular.module('mainApp')
    .factory("transformRequestAsFormPost",
        function () {
            function transformRequest(data, getHeaders) {
                var serializeData = function (obj, result, keyName) {
                    if (typeof (keyName) === 'undefined') {
                        keyName = null;
                    }
                    var cloneObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
                    $.each(cloneObj, function (idx, v) {
                        if (v instanceof Object) {
                            var newIdx = encodeURIComponent(idx);
                            var newKeyName = keyName === null ? newIdx : keyName + "[" + newIdx + "]";
                            serializeData(v, result, newKeyName);
                        }
                        else {
                            var key = encodeURIComponent(idx);
                            if (keyName !== null) {
                                key = keyName + "[" + key + "]";
                            }
                            result.push(
                                key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v)
                                );
                        }
                    });
                };
                var result = [];
                var headers = getHeaders();
                headers["Content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
                serializeData(data, result);
                return result.join("&");
            }
            return (transformRequest);

        });

app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    //$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

}
]);
function register() {
    alert("submit");
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("reg")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: this question could really use a better (and more specific) title....

Comment: What part of error don't you understand? If you don't inject it...it's not defined

Comment: Also seems like all you need is to use built in serializer and pass proper arguments to `$http.post`

Comment: The code has so many problems it is hard to find a place to start. Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use factory service as a function, and this service function itself is anonymous

your function must be in this format

`(function(data, headersGetter, status))`

read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) = > Transforming Requests and Responses